# How to prevent org-exporter from prepending "file://" to the beginning of absolute file paths when exporting to HTML?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-link

I use org-mode to write HTML pages for a website. When I use relative links for navigating the website's directory structure in my org-mode files and I export the org files to HTML, the links work as expected on the localhost.

On the localhost, beginning links with "/" should point to the website's root directory. However, when I use absolute links in my org files for linking to my website's other pages, the org-mode exporter automatically prepends "file://" to the beginning of all the absolute links when exporting the files to HTML. This is a problem because when I run the website on my localhost, the absolute links don't work. Nothing happens when I click on them.

Is there a way to prevent org-mode from prepending "file://" to the beginning of absolute file paths when exporting to HTML, so that all the absolute links behave the same way as relative links?